# Appending values with nested json objects

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop, append

I need to create a list from a JSON object that contains the address by states and cities.

The JSON object looks like:

```
atm = {estados": [
    {
        "txNome": "TOCANTINS",
        "listaCidades": [
            {
                "txNome": "PALMAS",
                "listaEnderecos": [
                    "AVENIDA JUSCELINO KUBITSCHEK. <br> Número: 0. <br> Bairro: PLANO DIRETOR NORTE. <br> CEP: 77.001-080.",
                    "AV 107 NORTE AVEN JUSCELINO KUBITSCHEK. <br> Bairro: PLANO DIRETOR NORTE. <br> CEP: 77.001-080."
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "txNome": "MARANHAO",
        "listaCidades": [
            {
                "txNome": "SANTA INES",
                "listaEnderecos": [
                    "AVENIDA CASTELO BRANCO. <br> Número: 2790. <br> Bairro: LARANJEIRAS. <br> CEP: 65.300-000.",
                    "ROD BR 316 KM 258. <br> Número: 32. <br> Bairro: CANAA. <br> CEP: 65.300-000.",
                    "AV CASTELO BRANCO. <br> Número: 2790. <br> Bairro: LARANJEIRAS. <br> CEP: 65.300-000."
                ]
            }
```

Following this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhaal/3v5y85uf/) I did this

```
var atms = <?php echo $scriptListaAtm ?>;

    ul = $('<div class="container">');


    for (var i = 0; i < atms.estados.length; i++) {

        var li = $('<h1>').text(atms.estados[i].txNome);

        var ul_cidade = $('<div class="col-md-4 botmargin">');

        for (var j = 0; j < atms.estados[i].listaCidades.length; j++) {

            var cidade = $('<h4>').text(atms.estados[i].listaCidades[j].txNome);
            var ul_endereco = $('<div>');

            for (var k = 0; k < atms.estados[i].listaCidades[j].listaEnderecos.length; k++) {
                $('<p>'+atms.estados[i].listaCidades[j].listaEnderecos[k]).appendTo(ul_endereco);
            }

            cidade.append(ul_endereco);
            ul_cidade.append(cidade);

        }

        li.after(ul_cidade);  
        li.appendTo(ul);

    }       
    ul.appendTo(locaisatendimento);
```

Using `li.after(ul_cidade)` doesn't work, I get only the states names, but if I use `li.append(ul_cidade)` it does work, but I get the wrong structure.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `atm = [estados": [` - starting right there, that's invalid. Am guessing you meant: `atm = {estados": [`

Comment: yeah, my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's because `li` is a node that you create and not a selector, `after` according to its description:

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

so there is no any element. Instead `li.append(ul_cidade)` append the content.

Comment: But how can I solve it? I just want to get the correct structure.

Comment: @AlexanderSoares What problem do you have? you wrote that with `append` function, it works, Why don't you use that function?

Comment: Because if I use append it will put the Cities inside the States divs, instead to add after each state div